# Angular ng-model on repeatable DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is it possible to define ng-model scope in Angular with HTML markup alone?

My markup:

```
<section>
    <button ng-click="boxOpen = !boxOpen">Open/Close</button>
    <div ng-show="boxOpen">Stuff in here</div>
</section>

<section>
    <button ng-click="boxOpen = !boxOpen">Open/Close</button>
    <div ng-show="boxOpen">Other stuff in here</div>
</section>
```

The problem with the above is 'boxOpen' is being globally interpreted by both, so clicking either of the buttons will show/hide both divs at the same time.

Anything helps, thanks!

Comment: Why not name the variable differently? Creating a new scope/controller  entirely seems overkill to me

Comment: I want to be able to reuse the markup in various places, without having to come up with a unique name for each one.

Comment: In this case, the best way is to create a directive, as [@BastienSander](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1361124/bastiensander) pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define 2 different controller, you will get two different scope

```
<section ng-controller="ctrl1">
     <button ng-click="boxOpen = !boxOpen">Open/Close</button>
     <div ng-show="boxOpen">Stuff in here</div>
</section>

<section ng-controller="ctrl2">
    <button ng-click="boxOpen = !boxOpen">Open/Close</button>
    <div ng-show="boxOpen">Other stuff in here</div>
</section>
```

You may also make a directive

**html**

```
<section my-show-hide-dir>
     <button ng-click="boxOpen = !boxOpen">Open/Close</button>
     <div ng-show="boxOpen">Stuff in here</div>
</section>

<section my-show-hide-dir>
    <button ng-click="boxOpen = !boxOpen">Open/Close</button>
    <div ng-show="boxOpen">Other stuff in here</div>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
     app.directive("myShowHideDir",
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs',
                function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                    $scope.boxOpen = false;
                }
            ]
        }

    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without adding a separate controller just for that (or something similarly ridiculous), you can't do it.

The best approach here would be to either make those buttons directives, each with their own isolate scopes... Or, use two different variable names, one for each button (or put them in an array if plan to have a lot of buttons).

But I strongly suggest taking the directive approach.